# SQL select all or nothing with IN clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables, where one is a map between the other two. Given a list of tags I want to select all other tags in which the taggables are tagged with. I'll try to given a visual of my problem.

```
tags
--------------
1 | 'email'
2 | 'gmail'
3 | 'yahoo'
4 | 'hotmail'
5 | 'school'
6 | 'not used'

taggables
--------------------------
1  | 'test1@gmail.com'
2  | 'test2@yahoo.com'
3  | 'test3@hotmail.com'
4  | 'test4@gmail.com'
5  | 'test5@myschool.edu'

tagged
------
1,  1   /* test1@gmail.com   --> email */
1,  2   /* test1@gmail.com   --> gmail */
2,  1   /* test2@yahoo.com   --> email */
2,  3   /* test2@yahoo.com   --> yahoo */
3,  1   /* test3@hotmail.com --> email */
3,  4   /* test3@hotmail.com --> hotmail */
4,  1   /* test4@gmail.com   --> email */
4,  2   /* test4@gmail.com   --> gmail */
5,  1   /* test5@myschool.edu--> email */
5,  5   /* test5@myschool.edu--> school */
```

So given a list of `'email', 'gmail'` the result set should be `'yahoo', 'hotmail', 'school'`. I've spent too much time on this and could use some help.

Comment: Are you sure your example results are correct?  If you run `select distinct taggableId from tagged where tagId In (1,2)`,  *every* taggableId from 1 to 5 is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach gets all items with the tags you want.  It then uses `in` to find all the tags on those items.  If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are asking for:

```
select distinct td.*
from tagged td join
     tags t
     on td.tagid = t.tagid
where td.itemid in (select itemid
                    from tagged td join
                         tags t
                         on td.tagid = t.tagid
                    where t.tagname in ('gmail', 'email')
                   ) and
      t.tagname not in ('gmail', 'email');
```

Comment: Had to add `EXCEPT SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE tag IN ('email', 'gmail')`

Comment: @E-rich . . . I did the same thing with an additional condition.  I was wondering if you cared whether the original tags were in the list or not.

Comment: Based on example results, he wants those omitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.tagname
FROM tags T
  JOIN tagged TT
    ON T.id = TT.tagID -- getting only used tags
  LEFT JOIN taggables TG
    ON TT.taggabeId = TG.ID
WHERE TG.id IS NULL        -- getting unassigned tags
  AND T.tagname IN ('gmail', 'email')  -- filtering by given confition
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to join the common table to itself - left column (with tagIds) joined to right column (with taggableIds)

```
Select distinct t.TagName  
From tags t
    join tagged d On d.tagId = t.TagId
    join tagged d2 On d2.taggAbleId = d.taggAbleId 
where d2.tagId in (1,2)
    and d2.tagid Not in (1,2)
```

or if you want predicate using string name, one more join

```
Select distinct t.TagName  
From tags t
    join tagged d On d.tagId = t.TagId
    join tagged d2 On d2.taggAbleId = d.taggAbleId 
    join tags t2 On t2.tagId = d2.TagId
where t2.tagName in ('gmail', 'email')
    and t2.tagtName Not in ('gmail', 'email')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name NOT IN ('email', 'gmail')

SELECT * FROM taggables 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tagged WHERE id_tag IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name NOT IN ('email', 'gmail')))
```